# Have we seen all of those Hanks?

Tags: comics, x-men, marvel, parallel-universe

In *Endangered Species* Hank McCoy goes on a quest to discover a scientific 'cure' for the events of the House of M. He asks every hero and villain he thinks might help. He nearly loses himself to this quest.

Steven Strange steps in, and shows him that it's not just science that is an option, and he shows him alternate realities in which his quest is one of religion, sorcery and technology etc:

[image]
[image]

Are these alternate Hanks ever discussed elsewhere? Do we see them again? I know that one of them featured is The Dark Beast, and that his story has been discussed. What about the others, who are they and where can I find out more about them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bulk of these images are derived from X-Factor Vol 3 #24 and the Endangered Species storyline. In almost all of these realities, the Hank McCoys of those worlds are very different from the canon one:

- Likely the Earth #616 Hank McCoy using the Avengers computer systems. (#1)
- The High Evolutionary has had little to do with mutants on Earth-616. In [X-men: Endangered Species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Endangered_Species), McCoy interacts with the High Evolutionary with no success; Earth-71224 (#2)
- Kavito Rao is unable to find a way to save Hank. From Earth-1294. (#3)
- An aquatic version of the Beast appears in Mutant X #1. He has a child-like intellect. (#4)
- Cyborg Beast researching a cure to the Mutant Extinction on Earth-2419. (#5)
- Red Hank and Bishop shooting guns together appear on Earth-3112 in X-Factor Vol 3 #24. I love the look. I rarely think of Hank in any color other than blue. (#6)
- Hank in arcane suspension, being monitored by Forge, Earth-9421. (#7)
- Hank as the leader of the Xavier Institute or the McCoy Institute. (The M-Men, anyone? Hey, he is riding in Xavier's chair, is probably unable to walk, otherwise why the chair) Hank would make a great headmaster on Earth-9142. (#8)
- Dark Beast, biochemist, evil genius. (#9)
- Hank McCoy, Sorcerer Supreme, Earth unknown, alternate reality (#10)
- Pope Beast appeared in X-Factor Vol 3 #24 as a request from to the Inhumans to borrow the Terrigen mists to save mutants from extinction. This is from Earth-7144. (#11)

Doctor Strange's trip was to show Hank divergent realities where if Hank had been a different man of different means, he would STILL be out there searching in whatever fashion his nature would have dictated. His goal is to show Hank, he is a searcher for truth no matter what kind of man he is, no matter where in time or space he is.

His goal is to remove Hank's doubt as to whether to search for a cure is the right thing, and instead to show him, no matter where he is, He is searching for a cure. Will we get to see any of those realities? Will Hank expand the nature of his search or the parameters of his search tools? In the end Hank will have to find Wanda Maximoff and see if he can prevent this event from coming to pass.